# Can't see hyperlink text within div container

Tags: html, css

I am recreating the Google homepage for an assignment on TheOdinProject. I am almost finished, but the problem I am having is that I can't seem to get the hyperlink to be visible within the footer container. I tried changing the text color, and I checked the properties within the list item selector and I should be able to see the hyperlink "About Google" but I can't. What am I doing wrong?

```
body {
font-family: Arial;
}
#logo {
       display: block;
        width: 350px;
        margin : 0 auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        }
input {
        margin-top: -50;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 2;
        display: block;
        width: 500px;
}
#logo img {
         max-width: 100%;
         }
.search_button {
margin-left: 800px;
margin-top: 5px;
display: inline;
float: left;
}
.feeling_lucky_button {
margin-right: 800px;
margin-top: 5px;
float: right;
display: inline;
}
#navbar {
background-color: #2d2d2d;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
#navbar ul {
margin-top: 5px;
padding-left: 8px;
}
li {
font-size: 13px;
padding: 5px 8px 5px 8px;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}
#navbar ul li a {
font-weight: bold;
color: #BBBBBB;
text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
position: fixed;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
#footer li {
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 8px;
}
#footer ul li a {
font-weight: bold;
color: red;
text-decoration: none;
}
#footer ul li a:hover {
color: red;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
}
#footer ul li a:link {
color: red;
}
#footer ul li a:visited{
color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Homepage Project</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Home</a></li>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="http://fineprintnyc.com/images/blog/history-of-logos/google/google-logo.png">
    </div>
    <div id="searchbar">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="searchbar">
    </div>
        <button class="search_button">Google Search</button>
        <button class="feeling_lucky_button">I'm feeling lucky</button>
    <div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com>About Google</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Run your HTML through a validator. You forgot to close your first unordered list, form, and quotes in the Google link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in footer. You missed double quote.

```
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">About Google</a></li>
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ywu325mw/1/

Comment: Correcting a typo by introducing two new typos....  There shouldn't be a > in the url, and <a> isn't self-closing...

Answer (score 0):

In your footer:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com>About Google</a>
```

should be:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">About Google</a>
```

You forgot to close `"` the `href` attr

Comment: I think you forgot to close the tag.

Comment: I think you missed double quotes as well.

Comment: I've showed him his example and where he missed, not a solution

Comment: Isn't href an attribute and not a tag?